# Перенос Верхнего меню в PHP

Tags: php

Надо вывести "Меню" `<li>` в код через PHP. Смысл в том, чтобы не повторять одну и тоже строку `<li>`, а сократить 8 строк в 1 php вывод.
(Простите за непонятное объяснение, я только начал программировать.)

```
   <div class="mainmenu-area" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#primary-menu">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/LOGO.png" alt="iPhone" class="navbar-brand logo">               
                    </a>
                </div>
                <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="primary-menu">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#home-page"><?php echo $lang['home-page'] ?></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#service-page"><?php echo $lang['service-page'] ?></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#feature-page"><?php echo $lang['feature-page'] ?></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#price-page"><?php echo $lang['price-page'] ?></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#team-page"><?php echo $lang['team-page'] ?></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#faq-page"><?php echo $lang['faq-page'] ?></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#blog-page"><?php echo $lang['blog-page'] ?></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact-page"><?php echo $lang['contact-page'] ?></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="lenguige">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="lenguige"><a href = "?lang=sk">|SK|</a></li>
                    <li class="lenguige"><a href = "?lang=en">|ENG|</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$menu = [
   ['langKey' => 'home-page', 'active' => true, 'link' => '#home-page'],
   ['langKey' => 'service-page', 'link' => '#service-page']
];

foreach($menu as $mi){
  echo '<li', 
            (isset($mi['active'])?' class="active"':''),
            '><a href="', $mi['link'], '">', $lang[$mi['langKey']],
        '</a></li>';
}
```

Мы создаем массив в котором помещаем наш список навигации на сайте. В качестве элемента массива используем еще массив с тремя составляющими: ключ массива lang, ссылку и состояние, активное или нет.

Полный пример:

```
<div class="mainmenu-area" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#primary-menu">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/LOGO.png" alt="iPhone" class="navbar-brand logo">               
                    </a>
                </div>
                <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="primary-menu">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <?php
                         $menu = [
                            ['langKey' => 'home-page', 'active' => true, 'link' => '#home-page'],
                            ['langKey' => 'service-page', 'link' => '#service-page']
                         ]; 

                         foreach($menu as $mi){
                           echo '<li', 
                                (isset($mi['active'])?' class="active"':''),
                                '><a href="', $mi['link'],'">',$lang[$mi['langKey']],
                                '</a></li>';
                         }

                        ?>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="lenguige">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="lenguige"><a href = "?lang=sk">|SK|</a></li>
                    <li class="lenguige"><a href = "?lang=en">|ENG|</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Увы не один из вариантов не подходит. Выдает ошибку : syntax error, unexpected 'home' (T_STRING), expecting ')' in

Comment: @Illia, на какую строку ругается?

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <?php foreach ($lang as $item): ?>
        <li><a href="#"><?php echo $item ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Но только вам еще нужно решить вопрос о хранении ссылок данных пунктов меню. К примеру лучше всего также хранить их (в вашем случае) в том же массиве $lang. И в цикле выводит title и href. Если переделать массив, то будет выглядеть код, примерно так:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

    <?php
    $lang = [
        'service-page' => ['href' => '/service', 'title' => 'Сервис'],
        'price-page' => ['href' => '/price', 'title' => 'Прайс'],
        'blog-page' => ['href' => '/blog', 'title' => 'Блог']
    ];

    ?>

    <?php foreach ($lang as $item): ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $item['href'] ?>"><?php echo $item['title'] ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

</ul>
```

Comment: В Вашем варианте вы переопределяете переменную $lang, какая скорее всего уже создана ранее

Comment: Это один из варианта наполнения массива с данными. Удивительно что это непонятно.

Comment: Увы не один из вариантов не подходит. Выдает ошибку : syntax error, unexpected 'home' (T_STRING), expecting ')' in

Comment: Если вы будете просто копировать варианты ответа в свой код, понятное дело что работать не будет. Нужно осмысленно внедрить цикл по массиву в ваш код, чтобы меню выводилось динамически.